# How to add space between buttons and it's borders?

Tags: html, css

[image]

What i have is a table with rows and columns and this is a picture of two rows and i have a border that continue without interruption which i did .. and every td has a button and what I want to do is to add space vertically and horizontally as you can see in the image in the arrow .. I mean under each button and on the left and right of the button without effecting the border , here is what i tried :

HTML Code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td width="188px" class="button"><img src="b2.png" /></td>

<td width="188px" class="button" ></td>
<td width="188px" class="button" ></td>
<td width="188px" class="button" ></td>
<td width="188px" class="button" ><img src="b1.png" /></td>
<td width="188px" class="button" ></td>
</tr>
```

Css code:

```
.button {
    width:180px;
    text-align:center;
    background:rgb(51,153,51);
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top:3px;
      margin-bottom:3px;
        margin-left:1px;
        margin-right:12px;
     /* add this */
}
.button a{
    display:block;
    height:37px;
    color:white;
    line-height:100px;
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}
.button:before {
    content:" ";
    display:block;
    width:180px;
    height:37px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:100%;
    transition:all 0.5s;
}
.button:hover:before {
    top:0;
}

table td {


    margin-top: 10px; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-left:1.0px solid #000;
    border-right:1.0px solid #000;
    border-spacing:5px;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;

}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Tried using `padding`?

Comment: yes but the button keep stretching and also i have tried margin but nothing has worked

Comment: can you create a fiddle with your issue?

Comment: Use [box-sizing: border-box](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) with `padding`.

Comment: Your css has `.button a` and there is no `<a>` tags in the shared html… seems strange. Either give the whole code, or remove the unnecessary code… Btw, "*and every td has a button"* - i think your understanding is incorrect. Here "*every td is a button*". In my answer to your previous question, "*every td has a button"*

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem :

I have change this :

```
<td class="button">
```

To this:

```
<td><div class="button">
```

Answer (score -1):

u can using padding in .button and .button:before increase height by 20px.Try this css..or refer to this [link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/aashi/A7rwL/)

```
.button {
    width:180px;
    text-align:center;
    background:rgb(51, 153, 51);
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    margin-left:1px;
    margin-right:12px;
    /* add this */
}
.button a {
    display:block;
    height:37px;
    color:white;
    line-height:100px;
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
    padding:10px;
}
.button:before {
    content:" ";
    display:block;
    width:180px;
    height:57px;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:100%;
    transition:all 0.5s;
}
.button:hover:before {
    top:0;
}
table td {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-left:1.0px solid #000;
    border-right:1.0px solid #000;
    border-spacing:5px;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```